# Prove $C(Int(A)) = \overline{C(A)}$

Tags: general-topology

This question has indeed been asked before, but this is a follow-up question regarding the use of DeMorgan's Law. The answer to the question posted previously does not use this method. Here's what I've done so far.

$Int(A) = \bigcup_{\alpha\in I}O_\alpha$, where $\{O_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in I}$ is the family of all open sets contained in A.

$\overline{A} = \bigcap_{\alpha \in I}F_\alpha$, where $\{F_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in I}$ is the family of all closed sets containing A.

Thus, $$C(Int(A)) = C\left(\bigcup_{\alpha\in I}O_\alpha\right) = \bigcap_{\alpha\in I}C\left(O_\alpha\right) =? \bigcap_{\alpha \in I}C(F_\alpha) = \overline{C(A)}$$

For this to be true, it must be the case that $\bigcap_{\alpha\in I}C\left(O_\alpha\right) = \bigcap_{\alpha \in I}C(F_\alpha)$, but I don't know why. My question is: is this equality true? If so, why? I also have a suspicion that I have written $\overline{C(A)}$ incorrectly.

EDIT: I think I've figured it out. If $\{O_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in I}$ is the family of all open sets contained in A, then I believe $\{C(O_\alpha)\}_{\alpha\in I}$ is the family of closed sets containing $C(A)$. Then the proof falls right out. Is this right?

Comment: Ah, I see you edited your question. Yes, your comment in your edit is correct!

Comment: If you leave out $=? \bigcap_{\alpha \in I}C(F_\alpha)$ then everything is okay under the remark you make in your edit. You proved that the complement of $int(A)$ coincides with the closure of the complement of $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't true that $\bigcap_{\alpha \in O} C(O_\alpha) = \bigcap_{\alpha \in I} C(F_\alpha)$; nor is it true that $\bigcap_{\alpha \in I} C(F_\alpha) = \overline{C(A)}$.

Also, knowing that $\overline{A} = \bigcap_{\alpha \in I} F_\alpha$, where $\{ F_\alpha \}_{\alpha \in I}$ is the family of all closed sets containing $A$, is not very useful here.

Rather, you need the information that $\overline{C(A)} = \bigcap_{\alpha \in I} \widetilde F_\alpha$ where $\{ \widetilde F_\alpha \}_{\alpha \in I}$ is the family of all closed sets containing $C(A)$.

Then observe that
$$ \{ \widetilde F_\alpha \}_{\alpha \in I} = \{ C(O_\alpha) \}_{\alpha \in O},$$
where $\{ O_\alpha \}_{\alpha \in O}$ is the family of open sets contained inside $A$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I like the tilde notation -- it makes the solution very clear.